# how to style ul list to be inline based off li class

Tags: html, css

I have a long unordered list with list items that have different classes.

let's do

level0

level1

I want them to display "inline" each time it comes to a level0 I want it to move back to the top and right of the last level0 so it looks like

Level0        Level0       Level0

Level1               Level1        Level1

Level1               Level1        Level1

Level1               Level1        Level1

These are auto generated so I can add extra classes or place divs to separate them. that would be too easy.

```html
<ul class="sitemap">
  <li class="level-0"><a href="https://popstops.com/graphic-inserts">Graphic Inserts</a></li>
  <li class="level-1" style="padding-left:20px;"><a href="https://popstops.com/graphic-inserts/stock-graphics">Stock Graphics</a></li>
  <li class="level-2" style="padding-left:40px;"><a href="https://popstops.com/graphic-inserts/stock-graphics/36-graphics">36" Graphics</a></li>
  <li class="level-2" style="padding-left:40px;"><a href="https://popstops.com/graphic-inserts/stock-graphics/18-graphics">18" Graphics</a></li>
  <li class="level-2" style="padding-left:40px;"><a href="https://popstops.com/graphic-inserts/stock-graphics/12-graphics">12" Graphics</a></li>
  <li class="level-2" style="padding-left:40px;"><a href="https://popstops.com/graphic-inserts/stock-graphics/72-graphics">72" Graphics</a></li>
  <li class="level-1" style="padding-left:20px;"><a href="https://popstops.com/graphic-inserts/editable-graphics">Editable Graphics</a></li>
  <li class="level-2" style="padding-left:40px;"><a href="https://popstops.com/graphic-inserts/editable-graphics/36-editable-graphics">36" Editable Graphics</a></li>
  <li class="level-2" style="padding-left:40px;"><a href="https://popstops.com/graphic-inserts/editable-graphics/12-editable-graphics">12" Editable Graphics</a></li>
  <li class="level-2" style="padding-left:40px;"><a href="https://popstops.com/graphic-inserts/editable-graphics/18-editable-graphics">18" Editable Graphics</a></li>
  <li class="level-2" style="padding-left:40px;"><a href="https://popstops.com/graphic-inserts/editable-graphics/72-editable-graphics">72" Editable Graphics</a></li>
  <li class="level-1" style="padding-left:20px;"><a href="https://popstops.com/graphic-inserts/custom-graphics">Custom Graphics</a></li>
  <li class="level-2" style="padding-left:40px;"><a href="https://popstops.com/graphic-inserts/custom-graphics/12-custom-graphics">12" Custom Graphics</a></li>
  <li class="level-2" style="padding-left:40px;"><a href="https://popstops.com/graphic-inserts/custom-graphics/18-custom-graphics">18" Custom Graphics</a></li>
  <li class="level-2" style="padding-left:40px;"><a href="https://popstops.com/graphic-inserts/custom-graphics/36-custom-graphics">36" Custom Graphics</a></li>
  <li class="level-0"><a href="https://popstops.com/popstops">Garage Stops</a></li>
  <li class="level-1" style="padding-left:20px;"><a href="https://popstops.com/popstops/18-garage-stop-493">18" Garage Stop</a></li>
  <li class="level-1" style="padding-left:20px;"><a href="https://popstops.com/popstops/36-garage-stop-455">36" Garage Stop</a></li>
  <li class="level-1" style="padding-left:20px;"><a href="https://popstops.com/popstops/72-garage-stop-494">72" Garage Stop</a></li>
  <li class="level-0"><a href="https://popstops.com/featured">Featured</a></li>
  <li class="level-0"><a href="https://popstops.com/displays">Displays</a></li>
  <li class="level-1" style="padding-left:20px;"><a href="https://popstops.com/displays/pop-displays">Pop Displays</a></li>
  <li class="level-1" style="padding-left:20px;"><a href="https://popstops.com/displays/retail-signage">Retail Signage</a></li>
  <li class="level-1" style="padding-left:20px;"><a href="https://popstops.com/displays/wheel-chocks">Wheel Chocks</a></li>
  <li class="level-0"><a href="https://popstops.com/other-uses">Other Uses</a></li>
  <li class="level-0"><a href="https://popstops.com/accessories">Accessories</a></li>
  <li class="level-1" style="padding-left:20px;"><a href="https://popstops.com/accessories/connector">Connector</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It would probably be better to change whatever is generating the list markup to instead generate appropriate html for the layout you have in mind....

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the HTML itself.

Comment: Please take a look at [ask]

Comment: You have a list of lists. Consider nesting your lists or using [definition lists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dt), again nested. Either way will give you greater control over styling.

Answer (score 0):

**If** you're willing to nest your lists, this becomes very easy.

I've given you a very basic example using `inline-block` to give you your columns. [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) could also be of benefit here.

```css
.sitemap {padding:0;}
.sitemap ul{padding-left:20px; padding-bottom:10px;}
.sitemap>li {display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; border-right: 1px solid black; padding-right: 2px;}
```

```html
<ul class="sitemap">
  <li><a href="https://popstops.com/graphic-inserts">Graphic Inserts</a>
    <ul class="level-1">
      <li><a href="https://popstops.com/graphic-inserts/stock-graphics">Stock Graphics</a>
        <ul class="level-2">
          <li><a href="https://popstops.com/graphic-inserts/stock-graphics/36-graphics">36" Graphics</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://popstops.com/graphic-inserts/stock-graphics/18-graphics">18" Graphics</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://popstops.com/graphic-inserts/stock-graphics/12-graphics">12" Graphics</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://popstops.com/graphic-inserts/stock-graphics/72-graphics">72" Graphics</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://popstops.com/graphic-inserts/editable-graphics">Editable Graphics</a>
        <ul class="level-2">
          <li><a href="https://popstops.com/graphic-inserts/editable-graphics/36-editable-graphics">36" Editable Graphics</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://popstops.com/graphic-inserts/editable-graphics/12-editable-graphics">12" Editable Graphics</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://popstops.com/graphic-inserts/editable-graphics/18-editable-graphics">18" Editable Graphics</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://popstops.com/graphic-inserts/editable-graphics/72-editable-graphics">72" Editable Graphics</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://popstops.com/graphic-inserts/custom-graphics">Custom Graphics</a>
        <ul class="level-2">
          <li><a href="https://popstops.com/graphic-inserts/custom-graphics/12-custom-graphics">12" Custom Graphics</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://popstops.com/graphic-inserts/custom-graphics/18-custom-graphics">18" Custom Graphics</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://popstops.com/graphic-inserts/custom-graphics/36-custom-graphics">36" Custom Graphics</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="https://popstops.com/popstops">Garage Stops</a>
    <ul class="level-1">
      <li><a href="https://popstops.com/popstops/18-garage-stop-493">18" Garage Stop</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://popstops.com/popstops/36-garage-stop-455">36" Garage Stop</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://popstops.com/popstops/72-garage-stop-494">72" Garage Stop</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="https://popstops.com/featured">Featured</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://popstops.com/displays">Displays</a>
    <ul class="level-1">
      <li><a href="https://popstops.com/displays/pop-displays">Pop Displays</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://popstops.com/displays/retail-signage">Retail Signage</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://popstops.com/displays/wheel-chocks">Wheel Chocks</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="https://popstops.com/other-uses">Other Uses</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://popstops.com/accessories">Accessories</a>
    <ul class="level-1">
      <li><a href="https://popstops.com/accessories/connector">Connector</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: yes i agree nesting would make the entire thing easier. However this is a list generated by magento, and I don't have the ability to edit and nest the list. So I am stuck with just the ability to apply styling to the li class.